# Why are year and quarter reputation rank the same number?

Tags: discussion

On Stack Overflow, why are my year and quarter reputation rank the same number?

Why have both if they are the same thing?

They have been exactly the same rank every time I've looked. It doesn't look like a coincidence.

Comment: We're still in the first quarter of the year, so the quarter and year are the same. Wait until April, and the quarter will differ from the year.

Comment: It is currently the first quarter of 2016 therefore logically all rep gained in 2016 is also the rep gained in the first quarter of 2016

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, ok if you answer I'll mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first quarter of the year, the Year and Quarter reputation rank will be the same. In the second quarter of the year, starting on April 1st (I'm not kidding ;)), the Year and Quarter reputation ranks will begin to diverge.

Comment: Here's a meta meta question. Why in the f#$%#$ would the answer have 4 up and no down and the question have 3 down?

Comment: I have no idea. [Meta voting is weird.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @toddmo Because the quality of an answer and it's question are not the same. I would imagine people thought the question was not useful for meta (since it turns out it was a simple logical mistake). I didn't downvote though, so who knows.